# Visual Basic 2013 Text duplicating

Tags: vb.net, duplicates

I had issues with a program, so
I was making a notepad program for my XP overlay thingy, and whenever I reopen it twice, the text is duplicated.

For example when I type in

```
test
```

and i reopen it second, it outputs:

```
testtest
```

I have no idea what is causing this, but it certainly is annoying.
If I could get some help with this issue that would be awesome!
Heres my code:

```
    Private Sub notepad_X_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles notepad_X.Click

    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\XP\notepad.txt", RichTextBox1.Text, True)
        RichTextBox1.Text = ""
    Catch Exc As System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\XP")
    End Try

    notepad.Enabled = False
    notepad.Visible = False
End Sub

Private Sub Notepad_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartM_Notepad.Click
    RichTextBox1.Text = ""
    Try
        RichTextBox1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\XP\notepad.txt")
    Catch Exc As System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory("C:\XP")
    End Try
    notepad.Enabled = True
    notepad.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you have explicitly specified it to do so. You are using the [**`FileSystem.WriteAllText()` overload with 3 parameters**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128035(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), where you've set the third parameter to True. That parameter (called `append`) specifies if you want to **append** text to your file or **overwrite** it.

As you've told it to append text to your file it will just write the new text you give it (whatever's in `RichTextBox1`) after the already existing text. Set the parameter to False so that the text gets overwritten instead:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\XP\notepad.txt", RichTextBox1.Text, False)
```

Comment: Thanks, the tutorial i followed said to put it as true, but thanks! After testing, it fully worked fine.

Comment: @cake2 : Glad to hear! Please mark my post as the accepted answer by pressing the check mark on its left, when possible (you usually have to wait 15 minutes after you've asked the question). -- Marking a post as the accepted answer will mark the question as resolved, and the answerer will be given 15 reputation points and the asker of the question will be given 2 reputation points.

Comment: @cake2 : Happy coding, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you, and happy coding to you. Screw Christmas, coding day is way better.